# Name of the set of points lying a given distance away from a curve along a line intersecting the curve's tangent at a given angle.

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Given a smooth curve $S$, I'd like to know the name of, and what we can say about the set of points $\left\{x | \exists\;y \in S, d(x, y) = \ell, \text{Angle between }\overleftrightarrow{xy} \text{ and } T(y) \text{ is } \theta \right\}$. Where $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes distance, and $T(y)$ is the line tangent to $S$ at $y$.

Since this is just something I've been wondering about, I'd also appreciate references to results about similar but not necessarily identical loci.

Comment: Apologies, am not a mathematician, so can't help with the maths aspects!  But, if you describe the curves using vector-valued functions $\vec{x}(t)$ and $\vec{y}(t)$, and $\lVert \vec{x}(t) - \vec{y}(t) \rVert = \ell$, and $$\frac{\bigr(\nabla \vec{y}(t)\bigr) \cdot \bigr(\vec{y}(t) - \vec{x}(t)\bigr)}{\lVert \nabla \vec{y}(t) \rVert \lvert \vec{y}(t) - \vec{x}(t) \rVert } = \cos\theta$$, then $x$ would be an offset curve to $y$ with, uh, "attack angle" $\theta$; with practical application in CNC and in vinyl cutting (drag-blade offsetting with a directional bias) and similar.

Comment: Ah that actually sounds quite similar to the situation I was thinking of. I dropped the directionality from my question, but it does exist in the original situation I had in mind. Do you have any references to properties of these curves?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.. That's why I'm interested in this, too (and hoped that adding a comment about the real-world use of such curves might sway some of the resident mathematicians here to answer).  I have worked out the "offset" curve for a polyline (piecewise linear curve), but the truly interesting ones, cubic curves (e.g. Bézier), were outside my maths capabilities. :(